# Can anyone identify/name this plumbing component?

Tags: plumbing, pex, fitting

Located under all the "AM/PM Kitchen" (bedroom) sinks in the house:

[image: Mystery Component]

It adapts the 3/8 PEX output from the mixer valve to 1/4 PEX to the spigot. The thing that looks like a valve does not appear to do anything.

Sorry I don't have a banana for scale, but it is a fairly small item as you can tell from the 3/8 and 1/4 inch PEX at the top.

It also appears to be totally devoid of brand or part markings.

The faucet is probably Delta™, but because the valve and the spigot are separate items, it is possible that they are not the same brand.

I am looking for proper terminology, or a link to a product page, etc.

Or just informative observations.

Comment: Do you know the maker of the faucet? That would be the first place to research.

Comment: It almost looks like a sediment filter with cleanout plug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer to my own question. I went to the Delta™ site after looking up Delta™ faucets on Amazon™, and discovered that this widget is indeed an *integral part* of the spigot -- it allows Delta™ sprayers to be plugged in and functions as the diverter. Or the diverter receptacle.

Unfortunately Delta™ doesn't offer a mating sprayer in the nickel finish that they sold this faucet in.

Alaska Man gets the kewpie doll for suggesting that I look at the faucet manufacturer website. I had been assuming that the widget was a separate component, and had not ever considered the idea that it was part of the faucet!